# Computing geometric series in R

Tags: r

I would like to compute:

```
$\sum_{j=1}^n r^j$ for $n=10, 20, 30, 40$, where $r=1.08$
```

http://quicklatex.com/cache3/76/ql_b64b957d43a0d6a93418cb18eb752576_l3.png

and to see the answers as a vector. I'm working with R; could anyone is able to explain to me how to do this?

Comment: What is r? A constant? For an atomic random normal `r`, `sapply(seq(10, 40, 10), function(x){sum(rnorm(1)^seq(x))})`

Comment: Fyi, R has documentation. For example, you can type `?sum` or `?sequence` or `??sequence`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of r is unstated and I guessing that the formula being requested is not really the correct solution to a compound interest problem, but here is one answer to the question as currently posed:

```
r = 5.3; for (n in c(10,20,30,40) ) print( sum( r^(1:n) ) )

[1] 21555896
[1] 3.769856e+14
[1] 6.593006e+21
[1] 1.153034e+29
```

Comment: The answer is not "as a vector" as asked in the question.

Comment: If that bothers you then try cumsum( r^(1:n) )[ seq(10,40,by=10) ]

Answer (score 3):

So you are playing with **power series**. You may do:

```
r <- 1.08  ## this will be a divergent series, toward `Inf`
rr <- r^(1:40)
cumsum(rr)[1:4 * 10]
# [1] 15.64549  49.42292 122.34587 279.78104
```

The theoretical value is

```
## define a function
f <- function (n, r) r * (1 - r ^ n) / (1 - r)

## call this function
f(1:4 * 10, 1.08)
# [1] 15.64549  49.42292 122.34587 279.78104
```

Note, the theoretical result is not `(1 - r ^ (n + 1)) / (1 - r)`, as you start summation from `j = 1` instead of `j = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps (if I interpreted the latex right):

```
library(purrr)

r <- 1.08
map_dbl(seq(10, 40, 10), function(n) {
  sum(r^(1:n))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only for loop and getting output as a vector:

```
out=c(); 
for(i in c(10,20,30,40)) 
   {sum=0; 
    for(j in 1:i)
      {sum=sum+1.08^j}; 
    out=c(out,sum)}; 
out
```

Output:

```
[1]  15.64549  49.42292 122.34587 279.78104
```

Or:

```
> out=c(); 
> for(i in c(10,20,30,40)) 
+     out=c(out,sum(1.08^(1:i)))
> out 
[1]  15.64549  49.42292 122.34587 279.78104
```

or, in R way:

```
> sapply(seq(10,40,10), function(x) sum(1.08^(1:x)))
[1]  15.64549  49.42292 122.34587 279.78104
```