# Is there a way to compute a geometric series in R for a matrix calculation?

Tags: r

I dont know if I've worded the question correctly, English isn't my first language.

I've tried the following already, unfortunately, it doesn't work.

```
M<-1:100
expm<-function (A,M) {
  sum(A^M/factorial(M))
}
expmy(A,M)
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823198/computing-geometric-series-in-r

Comment: You would need to define a power operator for square matrices. FYI there are some packages which compute the exponential of a matrix, such as **expm**.